# How can I change navigation current in React-Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, next.js

I'm using this code for header navigation.

```
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Main', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'Test', href: '/test', current: false },
  { name: 'Test 2', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Test 3', href: '#', current: false },
]
```

and in html:

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
    <a
        key={item.name}
        href={item.href}
        className={classNames(item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white', 'px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium')}
        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
    >
        {item.name}
    </a>
))}
```

How can I change current section to "true" when I route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to change the value of one of the items in the array for this use case.

In this case you can check what the current path is, which you can find in the router. Then you should check if the current path matches one of the href's.

```
const NavComponent = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return navigation.map((item) => (
        <a
            key={item.name}
            href={item.href}
            className={classNames(
                router.asPath === item.href
                    ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                    : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                'px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium'
            )}
            aria-current={router.asPath === item.href ? 'page' : undefined}
        >
            {item.name}
        </a>
    ));
};
```